# How do I scale a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have an array like

0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0

Is there a way that I can get this array to be double the dimensions so that let's so the new array is like this:

0,0,1,1,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? What is the original dimensions of your array and the final dimension you need?

Comment: also, can't you just use [numpy.resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)?

Comment: You want every row to be duplicated so `[a, b, c]` would become `[a, a, b, b, c, c]`, and every column to then be duplicated as well?

Comment: @AryanBansal numpy.resize would take array `[a, b, c]` and produce `[a, b, c, a, b, c]`

Comment: @Jared the question was edited after my comment. Earlier it was a lot more confusing and unclear so I wasn't sure what OP wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.repeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) should work here. I *think* you have to call it twice to get it to repeat in both axes.

```
a = np.array([[0,1,0],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,1,0]
             ])

a.repeat(2, axis=1).repeat(2, axis=0)
```

This gives you:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```